# Facebook login - check if user has a valid / verified Facebook account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, verification

I am using Facebook PHP SDK for facebook login to give comfort option for users. But I also want to check if user's facebook account is verified. For email there is a simple solution - if you request a "get-email permission" and user accepts - facebook then gives you the email ONLY if it has been verified.

Thing is, there is a growing number of users who verified their account with mobile/cell phone. I dont want to request a phone number from users so...

**How do I do some sort of general check that particular facebook user has a verified account?**
Is that even possible?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user , there is a response variable 'is_verified'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get user's "verified" status with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696484/how-to-get-users-verified-status-with-php)

Comment: @KA_lin dont get confused ! i̶s̶_̶v̶e̶r̶i̶f̶i̶e̶d̶  does something else! :) Well the answer is duplicate-ish but the question is a bit different :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, it is possible through Facebook Graph API see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user for more info.

One of the returns of the Graph API is a key called "**verified**" - it gives boolean, resp. 1 or 0.

> Indicates whether the user account has been verified. This is distinct from the is_verified field. Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions:
>   Register for mobile
>   Confirm their account via SMS
>   Enter a valid credit card

**Example of usage:**

```
  $me = yourApiCall(...); // your own call to https://graph.facebook.com/me
  $me = json_decode($me); //convert JSON to PHP object
  if( $me->verified ){
    // is verified
  } else {
    // is NOT verified
  }
```

**Don't get confused** with is_verified that does something else:

> People with large numbers of followers can have the authenticity of their identity manually verified by Facebook. This field indicates whether the user profile is verified in this way.

Comment: Just a disclaimer. The **"verified"** field has been deprecated as of 2018.

Comment: @monkfromearth what's the replacement ? :) I'd be happy to edit to add the new stuff :)